# How can i insert text into html tag in php string?

Tags: php, html, tags

i have been dealing with this for awhile and i could not figure out how to do the following in PHP:

```
$string = "this is test <pre>somrthing in <p>pharagraph</p></pre> dont know tell me <pre>value33 kooo ok</pre> this is php regress <pre>teeth value</pre> ok how"; 

function get_innercode($string) {
preg_match_all("#<pre>(.*?)</pre>#", $string, $foo); 
echo implode("\n", $foo[1]); 
}
    $insert1=get_innercode($string);



    $insert2=" 2 place me in the pre tag"; // you can ignore this

    $string="this is test  <pre> WHERE $insert1 SHOULD BE</pre> dont know tell me  <pre>WHERE $insert2 SHOULD BE</pre> ok how ";
```

how can i do this?
Please note i cannot do

```
$string="some text here <pre> WHERE $insert1 SHOULD BE</pre> some more text here <pre>WHERE $insert2 SHOULD BE</pre> ok how";
```

because i am getting $insert1 and $insert2 from $string to modify. i need to place it back in there where they come from.
thank you

Comment: should work as is ... just echo it ` echo $string;`

Comment: That will "work", fsvo - although it is potentially open to HTML injection, depending on where the data comes from. *What problem(s) are you having?*

Comment: I believe the question is: "How can I *extract* text inside <pre> elements?" To extract (take from) is different than to insert (put into). Please update the question/title for clarity.

Comment: $insert1 and $insert2 is extracted from those pre tags. i need to put them back in there after modifying.

Comment: Can you post a *minimal* example of intended code from the start to the end of the operation? That does not make much sense to me.

Comment: For reference, `$insert1 = get_innercode($string);` sets `$insert1` to null, since your function prints -- rather than returning -- a value.

Comment: -1 for a title that causes this question to be high in google search, when one is looking for how to include a php string in html text, which is NOT what this question is about, as pointed out by user2246674 in comments above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do:

```
$insert1 =" 1 place me in the pre tag";
$insert2 =" 2 place me in the pre tag";

$string = "some text here <pre>{$insert1}</pre> some more text here <pre>{$insert2}</pre> and may be some more text or ";
```

You can echo a variable from inside a string when it's wrapped around double quotes. This does not work with single quotes.

**Edit:** This might be what you are looking for then:

```
$string = "This my <code>awesome</code> code";

$string = preg_replace('/<code>(.*?)<\/code>/', '<pre>$1</pre>', $string);
```

Comment: You don't even need the braces for simple variables like this.

Comment: @Barmar that is correct but in some editors using the curly braces makes the variable stand out.

Comment: thanks but i am getting $insert1 and $insert2 fom the $string and modifying it. afterwards i want to put it back in there where they come from. So i cannot manually define it and print it.

Comment: @Justin: Then you need to clarify -- and show some real code.  Because your question's code is a rather bad example; as written, it works just fine.

Comment: @cHao is correct. From what you are describing it seems as thought `sprintf()` might be what you are looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: @Justin that still doesn't clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Justin: Your edit makes no sense.  Strings don't get a divorce or anything.  You can put them back together and they don't complain even once.

Comment: $string = "Lorem <pre>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <code>Donec sed erat vel diam ultricies commodo. Nunc</pre> venenatis tellus eu quam suscipit  dolor vehicula.</code>";
$regex = '#<code>(.*?)</code>#';
$code = preg_match($regex, $text, $matches);
//implode("\n", $matches);




$v = "this is test <pre>somrthing in <p>pharagraph</p></pre> dont know tell me <pre>value33 kooo ok</pre> this is php regress <pre>teeth value</pre> ok how"; 

function get_innercode($v) {
preg_match_all("#<pre>(.*?)</pre>#", $v, $foo); 
echo implode("\n", $foo[1]); 
}
 get_innercode($string); `

Comment: this is how i get thewm and i need to put them back

Comment: @Justin: I am not going to even try to read that.  It needs to go into the question -- and should probably replace your example, if it can actually replicate the problem.

Comment: @Justin this really doesn't make sense. What are you trying to accomplish with this? There might be a better way to do it if you explain what you are trying to do, we might be able to help.

Comment: well i think i am lacking to show what i need here. $string1 is the text inbeetween pre tag and the $string2 is also the text inbetween pre tag and i am modifying it with some function. later i need to put those modified text back in those pre tags. that is all

Answer (score 0):

In php you can concatenate strings with a "." before and after, example:

```
$var1 = "hello";
$var2 = "What's up";

$concat = "Hey, ".$var1." ,".$var2."<br>";

echo $concat;
```

Comment: As copied from another answer: Normal string interpolation, as posted, achieves the same results. Hence this is no improvement or solution (although I'm still not sure what the actual problem is).

Answer (score 0):

Similar methodology here. This allows for larger areas to be filled

```
$insert[0] = "Some Text";
$insert[1] = "Some More Text";

function Parser($content){
$i = 0;
    while (preg_match_all('`\<pre\>(.*?)\</pre\>`', $content, $matches)) {
       foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $match) { 
         //$innertext = $matches[1][$key]; //replace with your preferred filler
         $innertext = $insert[$i]; //such as this
         $replacement = '<pre>' . trim($innertext) . '</pre>';
         $content = str_replace($match, $replacement, $content); 
         $i++;
       }
    }
}
```

Parse your line(s) of content like so:

```
Parser("this is test <pre> WHERE $insert1 SHOULD BE</pre> dont know tell me  <pre>WHERE $insert2 SHOULD BE</pre> ok how");
```

This is untested so may have a couple of bugs in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I am adding div tag before each pre content. You can also modify content as needed by using $matches[1]

```
$string_new = preg_replace_callback(
   '#<pre>(.*?)</pre>#',
    function ($matches) {
        return "<div>".$matches[0]."</div>";
    },
    $string
);

echo $string_new;
```